# Last Row edit for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet trigger that **splits the values** in Column F when any value in that column gets edited. However I want the script to only split the 'last row', and not all the rows (even the ones above already split)

[image]

Which line of code should I add to have the script only split the last edited row in column F and not the entire range? This is my sample so far:

```
    function Split() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').splitTextToColumns();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA);
};
```

Kind regards,
Brendon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reflect `splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA)` to the column "F" of the last row of the active sheet.

In this case, you can use `getLastRow()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function Split() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').activate();
  // spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').splitTextToColumns();
  // spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F50').splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA);
  spreadsheet.getRange("F" + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getlastrow)